# Fetching everytime from database or keeping them in static fields?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, static

I have to fetch list of companies throughout my application.
The companies are saved in sqlite.
My question is, do I keep the list of companies in a static variable like this,

```
private static List<Company> companies;
    public static List<Company> getCompanies() {
        if (companies == null) {
            companies = fetchCompaniesFromDb();

        }

        return companies;
    }
```

Or fetch each time from database?

```
public static List<Company> getCompanies() {
    return fetchCompaniesFromDb();

}
```

Which is a better solution?
The methods are just for demonstration, in reality I am doing the fetching in different thread.

Comment: How often is this information retrieved/accessed? How much data are we talking about? And how often does it change?

Comment: I would use [Loaders](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html), if you need  help with them I can give you some basic code.

Comment: You might want to use a caching tool such as EHCache then you can also set up a call to clear the cache when you want to. Also EHCache will hold large amounts of data.  You can also set up a task to clear the cache everynight or once a month depending on how often it need to be refreshed

Comment: Definitely don't store it in a static field.  A static field that can change over time is basically always a design smell.  You can store it in an instance field, though.

Comment: checkout how LruCache works [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LruCache.html)

Comment: @JoeONeil does EHCache work with android, please look into this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45672912/java-lang-exceptionininitializererror-when-creating-instance-of-ehcache-in-andro