# java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError when creating instance of EHCache in android

Tags: java, android, caching, ehcache

I am trying to use ehCache in Android, and getting the following error

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at net.sf.ehcache.EhcacheDefaultClassLoader.getInstance(EhcacheDefaultClassLoader.java:29)
    at net.sf.ehcache.config.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:208)
    at net.sf.ehcache.config.ConfigurationFactory.parseConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:152)
    at net.sf.ehcache.config.ConfigurationFactory.parseConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:103)
    at net.sf.ehcache.config.ConfigurationFactory.parseConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:140)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.newInstance(CacheManager.java:892)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.create(CacheManager.java:873)
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.getInstance(CacheManager.java:907)

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: parentLoader == null && !nullAllowed
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.<init>(ClassLoader.java:210)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.<init>(ClassLoader.java:202)
    at net.sf.ehcache.EhcacheDefaultClassLoader.<init>(EhcacheDefaultClassLoader.java:35)
    at net.sf.ehcache.EhcacheDefaultClassLoader.<clinit>(EhcacheDefaultClassLoader.java:26)
    at net.sf.ehcache.EhcacheDefaultClassLoader.getInstance(EhcacheDefaultClassLoader.java:29) 
    at net.sf.ehcache.config.Configuration.<init>(Configuration.java:208) 
    at net.sf.ehcache.config.ConfigurationFactory.parseConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:152) 
    at net.sf.ehcache.config.ConfigurationFactory.parseConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:103) 
    at net.sf.ehcache.config.ConfigurationFactory.parseConfiguration(ConfigurationFactory.java:140) 
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.newInstance(CacheManager.java:892) 
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.create(CacheManager.java:873) 
    at net.sf.ehcache.CacheManager.getInstance(CacheManager.java:907)
```

here is my code where I am trying to initialize

```
private static Cache getCache(String cacheName) throws IllegalStateException{
    CacheManager cacheManager = CacheManager.getInstance();
    Cache cache;
    if(!cacheManager.cacheExists(cacheName)) {
        cacheManager.addCache(cacheName);
    }
    cache = cacheManager.getCache(cacheName);
    return cache;
}
```

Looks like EHCache won't work in android? Can anybody put some light on this?
After I got the error, I have also put a ehcache.xml with some configuration inside res/xml/
The **ehcache.xml**

```
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="ehcache.xsd" updateCheck="true"  monitoring="autodetect" dynamicConfig="true">

    <!-- By default, Ehcache stored the cached files in temp folder. -->    <!-- <diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir" /> -->

    <!-- Ask Ehcache to store cache in this path -->    <!--<diskStore path="c:\\cache" /> -->

    <!-- Sample cache named cache1
    This cache contains a maximum in memory of 10000 elements, and will expire
    an element if it is idle for more than 5 minutes and lives for more than
    10 minutes.

    If there are more than 10000 elements it will overflow to the
    disk cache, which in this configuration will go to wherever java.io.tmp is
    defined on your system. On a standard Linux system this will be /tmp" 
    -->     
    <cache name="cache1" maxEntriesLocalHeap="10000" maxEntriesLocalDisk="1000" eternal="false" diskSpoolBufferSizeMB="20" timeToIdleSeconds="300" timeToLiveSeconds="600" memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU" transactionalMode="off">         
        <persistence strategy="localTempSwap" />
    </cache>

</ehcache>
```

Comment: pls show your ehcache.xml

Comment: I have attached the xml

Answer (score 0):

Ehcache is not able to locate the ehcach.xml file. It has no idea about res/xml folder.

So try to configure your cache programmatically in this way (ehcache 2.10):

```
// create default CacheManager
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.setName("Mngmt");
// [...]
CacheManager cacheManager = CacheManager.create(config);

int maxEntriesLocalHeap = 100;
String cachName = "cacheName";
Cache cache = new Cache(
  new CacheConfiguration(cachName, maxEntriesLocalHeap)
    .memoryStoreEvictionPolicy(MemoryStoreEvictionPolicy.LFU)
    .eternal(false)
    .timeToLiveSeconds(120)
    .timeToIdleSeconds(60)
    .diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds(0));
cacheManager.addCache(cache);
```

More Information you will find here: [Creating Caches Programmatically](http://www.ehcache.org/documentation/2.8/code-samples.html#creating-caches-programmatically)

Comment: Thanks, but I am getting the error in 
cacheManager =CacheManager.getInstance();
I have tried this, but to no effect

Comment: try to call `create` instead of `getInstance`

Comment: Same problem. getInstance does nothing except calling create.