# java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError when creating instance of EHCache in android adain

Tags: java, android, ehcache

I am trying to use ehCache in Android, and getting the following error

```
08-01 10:26:11.308 1645-1645/com.example.ehcache.ehcache_test E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.ehcache.ehcache_test, PID: 1645
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.ehcache.ehcache_test/com.example.ehcache.ehcache_test.MainActivity}: net.sf.ehcache.CacheException: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2902)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3037)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1797)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6642)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

here is my code where I am trying to initialize

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        CacheManager manager = CacheManager.getInstance();

        try {
            manager.addCache("myCache");
            Cache myCache = manager.getCache("myCache");
            myCache.put(new Element("hoge", "HOGE"));

            myCache = manager.getCache("myCache");
            Element element = myCache.get("hoge");
            System.out.println("myCache.hoge = " + element.getObjectValue());
        } finally {
            manager.shutdown();
        }

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

ehcache.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ehcache.org/ehcache.xsd">
    <cache name="myCache"
        maxEntriesLocalHeap="0">
    </cache>
</ehcache>
```

Directory tree
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBj0Z.png)

This problem was previously defined, but it has not yet been resolved.
[java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError when creating instance of EHCache in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45672912/java-lang-exceptionininitializererror-when-creating-instance-of-ehcache-in-andro)

I will be waiting for any answers.

Answer (score 0):

We would need the source of the CacheException to tell you what is going on. However, I wouldn't be that surprised if it doesn't work. Ehcache 2.x isn't maintained anymore.

You might want to try Ehcache 3.x instead. If it doesn't work, we will fix it right away. :-)